# React isomorphic inconvenience

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm building isomorphic app using `Node.js` and `ReactJS`.

I've met a situation when inside some isomorphic `React` component (rendered both on client and server sides) I need to include only client-side dependency (some notifications library for example).

What is the best way to have it worked (compiled) both on server/client sides?

**P.S:** I have few thoughts about possible workarounds something like checking for browser env variables (ex. some `typeof window !== 'undefined'`) etc. but I'm not sure it's a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lifecycle method `componentDidMount` which is not invoked on the server instead of checking if window is undefined.

The "downside" is if your client side dependency enhances an element for example or changes any property of it, it'll get the default property first since it was rendered server side and when `componentDidMount` runs it'll get changed causing a "blink".

Comment: as I said for ex. I need to include `notificatoins` lib. I want to include it once, for that I need to have `componentDidMount` only in the top-level React component, right? Is there a way to pass it (dependency reference) through entire components hierarchy safely then?

Comment: Just include it where ever you need it, i mean you need to require it from somewhere or are you looking to conditional load some javascript?

Comment: I thought I could include it just once globally and then use whenever I need. And I'd not like to require it inside `componentDidMount` which may require it many times later dynamically depends on mounting elements.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that's correct. If it's already included globally then you can refer to it in your component which can be wherever in the hierarchy.

Comment: yea.. it's ok for client-side for example, but nodejs don't understand this require :) or vice-versa

Comment: Ah, I understand now - the library you want to use isn't made for Node. Okay, what you need to do then is to have two bundles, 1 for the server and 1 for the client. Or at least, that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using browserify I often use `process.browser` which is only true in browserified code.

If you wanted to get fancy and remove server code from the browser instead there is also [isbrowser](https://github.com/DylanPiercey/isbrowser) which will do just that.

Another way (webpack or browserify) is to take advantage of the [browser field](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec) in the package.json. You can make it so that the server requires a noop file and the browser requires a file the exposes the client side api.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined variable in webpack configuration file called process.env.WEBPACK and in my code when i need something like bottstrap js or something else i just write

```
  if(process.env.WEBPACK){
     //awesome lib included or scss or whatever
  }
```